# Выборка данных, обратная

Tags: sql, sql-server

Выбираю данные из таблицы следующим образом

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT clientid,productid,[DATE],
(SELECT quantity FROM csv_export c1 WHERE c.clientid=c1.clientid AND c.productid=c1.productid AND c.[DATE]=c1.[DATE]) AS quantity ,
(SELECT amount FROM csv_export c1 WHERE c.clientid=c1.clientid AND c.productid=c1.productid AND c.[DATE]=c1.[DATE]) AS amount
FROM dbo.CSV_Export c
WHERE
quantity>0
AND
amount>=0
```

А как мне получить те записи, которые не проходят указанные условия, то есть не являются уникальными по трём полям и не quantity>0
and
amount>=0

**update**

```
select 
distinct clientid,productid,[date],
(select quantity from csv_export c1 where c.clientid=c1.clientid and c.productid=c1.productid and c.[date]=c1.[date]) as quantity ,
(select amount from csv_export c1 where c.clientid=c1.clientid and c.productid=c1.productid and c.[date]=c1.[date]) as amount,
(select id from csv_export c1 where c.clientid=c1.clientid and c.productid=c1.productid and c.[date]=c1.[date]) as id
from dbo.CSV_Export c
where
quantity>0
and
amount>=0
```

Вопрос теперь, как отсюда вытащить только записи с полем id.

**update1:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот такие исходные данные.

Нужно с минимальным количеством кода из этой таблицы перенести в таблицу А - данные по условию
 - запись должна быть уникальна по набору полей клиент-товар-дата;
 - количество > 0 и сумма >= 0
в таблицу Б - данные, где это условие не выполняется

Comment: А "не являются уникальными" - это те которые повторяются 2 и более раза ? А сами то условия просто меняете на противоположные и AND меняется на OR, потому что вам получается надо выбрать записи где quantity<=0 ИЛИ amount < 0

Comment: @Mike не могу понять пока, как выразить эту противоположность, в случае с Distinct, в коде

Comment: Вы словами скажите что хотите получить на выходе, только строки, которые повторяются или все таки все строки. и если только те, которые повторяются, то сколько раз, столько сколько есть или достаточно одной записи, возможно с количеством повторений (намек на `group by и проверку having count(1) > 1`)

Comment: В целом задача такая: у меня есть таблица с данными. Мне нужно выполнить запрос, который А - при выполнении условий (3 поля должны быть уникальными и количество >0) перекинет из таблицы данные во вторую таблицу Б - при невыполнении любого из условий - перекинет данные в третью таблицу. Сейчас сделал так, что в изначальной таблице просто добавил поле id, сделал выборку по усвловиям, и те что в эту выборку не попали по id и попадают в третью таблицу. Но как-то попахивает костыльностью такой вариант @Mike

Comment: На счет уникальности все таки не ясно. Да, вы переносите именно уникальные значения, но вы не проверяете были ли они изначально уникальными или они такими стали после distinct, а значит в ту таблицу попадут и те записи что встретились один раз и те что много. но перенесуться конечно в одном экземпляре. А раз так, то уникальность строк вообще не имеет отношения к вопросу, просто меняйте условия в where и все. И distinct либо ставите либо нет в зависимости от того, что требуется получить в третьей таблице

Comment: @Mike я отредактировал вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Я всмотрелся в запрос ... Надо бы понять что требуется. потому что сейчас он выбирает как попало. Предположим у вас есть две записи с одинаковыми клиентом, продуктом и датой. При этом у одной из них quantity=0 (т.е. не попадает под условие). Так вот в результате выполнения вы запросто можете получить запись в которой подзапрос quantity выберет именно 0, потому что это подзапрос, он работает отдельно. А условие where проверяет не то что возвращает подзапрос, а таблицу, которая в from. И больше того: текущий вариант может вернуть quantity от одной записи, а amount от другой !

Comment: Так что лучше покажите пример входных данных и что на основе этих данных должен был бы получить тот запрос, который вы указали и что  должен получить запрос о котором вы спрашиваете

Comment: Да, этот момент я упустил.. Поправил вопрос @Mike

Comment: Надо рассматривать крайние варианты. вот например https://pastebin.com/gt2TQmWg, что из таких данных должно попасть в таблицу A и что в таблицу Б. Тут есть даже повторы с подходящими условиями (id 2 и 3) ваш текущий запрос вернет одну запись и при этом amount=100, quantity=200 (т.е. взять из разных). Так вот надо определиться, какая из записей нужна на выходе (указать некую сортировку в порядке которой надо взять первую или последнюю запись).

Comment: В том и проблема, что я голову поломал, как это нужно сделать, а с чем именно определиться - я вас к сожалению не могу понять, мне кажется условия заданы вполне конкретно @Mike

Comment: Я привел 4 записи, первые 3 поля в них одинаковы. в первую таблицу должна попасть как я понял только 1 запись. Скажите id той записи, данные из которой должны попасть в таблицу А. Если же туда должно попасть что то иное, а не 1 целая исходная запись, то скажите что должно быть в полях amount и  quantity. И что при этом должно попасть в таблицу Б - оставшиеся 3 записи или только одна запись, но тогда опять же какая конкретно из этих 4х

Comment: @Mike отталкиваемся от картинки, что в update1: 1 строка, проверяем, есть ли во всей выборке строки с таким же клиент-продукт-дата, если таких записей больше нет, И в этой записи количество > 0 и сумма >= 0 - то это запись должна быть помещена в таблицу А, если хотя бы одно из условий НЕ выполняется - т.е. допустим во всей выборке уже есть строка с теми же клиент-продукт-дата, либо количество <=0 либо сумма <0 - запись должна попасть в таблицу Б

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таблицу *A* вставляем записи следующим образом:

```
insert into A(....)
select clientid,productid,[DATE],quantity,amount
  from (
    select *, 
           count(1) over(partition by clientid,productid,date) cnt
      from CSV_Export
  ) X
  where quantity>0 AND amount>=0 AND cnt=1
```

В таблицу *Б* следующим:

```
insert into A(....)
select clientid,productid,[DATE],quantity,amount
  from (
    select *, 
           count(1) over(partition by clientid,productid,date) cnt
      from CSV_Export
  ) X
  where quantity<=0 OR amount<0 OR cnt>1
```

В данном случае используем оконную функцию count() для подсчета записей в пределах требуемой группировки, не зависимо от получения конкретных строк. Далее применяем к этой выборке требуемые условия.